# validating controls as a group. silverlight

Tags: silverlight, validation

I have a Silverlight page that is using MVVM. on the page I have several controls that I need to validate. for dropdowns and text boxes it is not so hard. i.e.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay,       ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:UpdateOnTextChangedBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

and I get the nice little red box with my message that I bound in the model.

but I also have a place were I have two check boxes in a stackpanel. I need to make sure one of the boxes is check. and I would like the error message to show up ether next to the stackpanal or the labeltextbox that is the 1st item in the stackpanal.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="6"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ac:LabelTextBox Content="Business Group(s):"  />
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    IsThreeState="False"
                    Content="XXX"
                    IsChecked="{Binding User.HasXXXUserRole, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                    Margin="3"
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight">


        </CheckBox>
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  IsThreeState="False"
                  Content="YYY"
                  IsChecked="{Binding User.HasYYYUserRole, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                  Margin="3"
                  FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Can both be checked or is it one or the other?  If only one can be checked, use radio buttons, not check boxes.

Comment: both can be checked. but at lest one has to be checked. ya. I would love a radio button. but no.